# How to plot a transparent cube with mayavi?

Tags: python, vtk, enthought, mayavi

Basically this is the question - how to plot a transparent cube with given coordinates of two opposite corners. Surely something simple exists, but I cannot find it. I have tried using `tvtk.visual.box`, but it doesn't support transparency as far as I could tell.